# How to call and pass values to parameterized function in PostgreSQL using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm looking to call a parameterized function in PostgreSQL using Node Js.
My function in PostgreSQL looks like as follows:

```
Create or replace FUNCTION public."InsertData"(ColType varchar(80))
Returns void
   AS $$
   BEGIN
    insert into public."MyTable"("ColType") values(ColType);
   RETURN;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And my Code for calling that function with parameteres is like:

```
client.query('SELECT "InsertData"($1)', [req.body.ColType],
```

But I'm not able to execute it successfully.

Getting error as :

```
Error in transaction error: function InsertData(unknown) does not exist
Error in transaction error: function InsertData(unknown) does not exist
```

But I can see my function as well as table table there in my DB. Also assigned all access roles like execute and all. Can any body tell me what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: What client library are you using? `node-pg`?

Comment: Your `req.body.ColType` doesn't resolve into any value, so the call signature cannot match any existing function.

Comment: @MattMorgan: I'm using Node PG `"pg": "^7.0.3"`.

Comment: @vitaly-t: I can see value in `req.body.ColType`, I don't that issue is creating error.

Comment: It might be that your data cannot be automatically converted into varchar(80).

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help and efforts, I resolved this issue by updating my code in node js where I was calling postresql function as below: Old code `client.query('SELECT "InsertData"($1)', [req.body.ColType],`  and new Code is : `client.query('SELECT "public"."InsertData"($1)', [req.body.ColType],`